# How to find properties of supercritical CO2 as a working fluid in a system

Tags: fluid-mechanics, thermodynamics, pressure, temperature

I'm working on a process flow currently and am using carbon dioxide as the working fluid because of its heat properties and because it's an inert gas. In the reactor that I am designing I'm looking to operate at 4 atmospheres (~58.78 psia) and at around 977°F (~500°C). I know it would be a supercritical fluid at this P-T relation but can not find any information on the properties of carbon dioxide at these conditions.

How would I go about finding or calculating for the thermodynamic properties at these conditions for carbon dioxide and then be able to continue this calculation through the entire process I'm designing?

Comment: This link may help : http://www.centrogalileo.it/nuovapa/Articoli%20tecnici/INGLESE%20CONVEGNO/CO2/Cavallini%20-%20Milano04CO2.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coolprop is a free API that's very similar to RefProp (not free):
http://www.coolprop.org/contents.html